# Homepage & Keywords Optimization

Tags: seo, keywords, site-structure

I am currently creating a website and because i am a total nooby in SEO i have some questions regarding the Keyword / Site structure of the Startpage.

Lets say my Website is about Reiki and courses i offer.The Startpage / url has the name Reiki and different sections that contain the short form of the text for the subpages.

For example:

1. "What is Reiki" section with short text about Reiki with a button that links to the "What is Reiki subpage" where everything will be explained
   in a more detailed way and for a better chance to rank for the Keyword "Reiki"
2. "What can Reiki do for me" section with short text about the benefits of doing Reiki with a link to "Benefits-Of-Reiki page
3. "About me" section which links to the "About Me Page" which tells more about me and how i got to reiki.

So if the home page is about Reiki in general and for example should present the user the subpages where he can get more details (What is Reiki, Benefits of Reiki, About me), it seems quite difficult not to use the same keywords that were used on the home page, especially if these are the keywords with the highest search volume. From my understanding it would be a problem to use some of the same keywords in the subpages that were already used on the startpage.  So what would be the best way to structure the page?

Comment: Stop focusing on keywords - that's a 20 year old, outdated technique.  Google isn't looking for exact matches.  Instead, it wants to match user intent.  Write good content, that fits with the page.  For example your "about me" page should be about you, not your company or even your services.  Ask yourself, what would your users expect to find on your home page vs your about me page and write accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Trebor's comment, above, which is spot on, yes it's fine to use some of the same keywords in the subpages that were already used on the start page. Most likely, your home page will outrank your deeper pages anyway. Unless one of those pages becomes very popular, and will outrank the home page for a certain query.

To that extent, what I'd recommend is for you to focus on:

1. User experience. Do the site's home page and information architecture make sense to you? To your audience? Is this how you're comfortable presenting information? Maybe get a couple of friends or people from the Reiki community to click around and tell you if they found what they'd hoped.
2. Structured data and rich results. With rich results, your content will stand out on the SERP, and potentially draw clicks and collect inbound links. Look at what your competitors are doing and how they're getting their rich results into the SERP, and see if you can beat them at their own game.